# How to filter Stack OverFlow questions depending upon the tags which I prefer

Tags: datatables

Let me know if this is duplicate of any other existing thread and route me to the original post. I am using the SO for nearly around 2 months.

Currently I am working on one tech( JQuery DataTable) and searching all over the google ans SO for the answers that can solve my issues. In this learning process I am trying to look for other users who post their questions on DataTables but I did not find a way to filter the SO questions so that I can view only those question which are for the required topic( like java, sql or datatables in my case). I have added 'datatables' as my fav tag to my profile and added 13 other tags in the 'ignore tags' section but still I can see lot more questions with other new tags which I do not want to add them all to my Ignore tag section as because I will end up adding 30+ or more tags.

So can come one tell if there is way I can filter the question based on the tags that I can only those question which I preferred? or there is way I should give feedback to SO to add this feature(if it is not present now) in future.

Comment: This question belongs on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) since it is about StackOverflow itself and not about programming.

Comment: oh opps... thanks for the info. I will delete it and repost it there

Comment: [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315301/how-to-filter-stack-overflow-questions-depending-upon-the-tags-which-i-prefer) Here is the link to my post at meta.